# WPF tags without hyphens

Tags: feature-request, tags

I went to ignore some wpf-related tags, and in the process of doing so, autocomplete alerted me to the existence of `wpfdatagrid` and `wpftoolkit`.

Further mucking about revealed that `wpf-toolkit` and `wpftoolkit` are synonyms. However, `wpf-datagrid` and `wpfdatagrid` are not. A search for `[wpfdatagrid]` returns 949 results, whereas a similar search with its hyphenated counterpart returns no results (regardless of tab selected).

It seems like the latter two should either by synonyms or the non-hyphenated tag eliminated.